# How to do SEO for dynamically user generated content?

Tags: seo

I've read tens of SEO guides and none of them seem to talk about this kind of stuff, I understand that if I have a static website like a blog, I got to pay attention to keywords, title, relevancy all that.

But, what if my website uses dynamic content with query parameters, and all that content is generated from the back-end, like here on stack for example, you go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"question" and then ther's a query string that pulls the data.

Can pages like that be crawled, because they don't really exist.

Every guide I've found seems to talk about static websites, I understand that all that is applicable too but, is there some other steps you need to do for dynamic content that affects SEO?

Comment: They can be crawled *if* there are links (url vars included) which exist hard coded somewhere. Obviously, Google's spider won't submit some complex form to generate the page. But if the resulting URL with GET vars exists hard-coded as a link somewhere else, it will treat that results page as if it's static. ..Your next problem is going to be duplicate content issues though.